# How can I hit multiple html buttons at once in javascript?

Tags: javascript, keydown, onkeydown, onkeyup

I can click the arrow buttons on the web page, but multiple buttons cannot be read at the same time.If I click on 37 and 39 keys it does not work but only when I click on 37 keys it works. Same goes for other keys, how can I control more than one button at the same time?

```
const handleArrowButtonMouseDown = function() {
  $('button').on('mousedown touchstart', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(state.arrowPressed) return;
    let direction = $(e.target).closest('button').attr('id');
    state.setArrowPressed(direction);
    state.setRobotCommand();
  });
};

const handleArrowButtonMouseUp = function() {
  $('button').on('mouseup mouseleave touchend', endCurrentOperation);
};


const handleArrowKeyDown = function() {
  $(document).keydown((e) => {
    if(state.arrowPressed) return;
    switch(e.which) {
      
    case 37: 
      state.setArrowPressed('left');
      break;

    case 38: 
      state.setArrowPressed('up');
      break;

    case 39: 
      state.setArrowPressed('right');
      break;

    case 40: // down
      state.setArrowPressed('down');
      break;

    default: return; 
    }
    e.preventDefault(); 
    state.setRobotCommand();
  });
};

const handleArrowKeyUp = function() {
  $(document).keyup((e) => {
    if (e.which === 37 && state.arrowPressed !== 'left') return;
    if (e.which === 38 && state.arrowPressed !== 'up') return;
    if (e.which === 39 && state.arrowPressed !== 'right') return;
    if (e.which === 40 && state.arrowPressed !== 'down') return;  
    endCurrentOperation();
  });
};
```

Comment: Store the pressed keys into an object or array, and check that object when you need the information of the pressed keys. Also, use standard [key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead of `which`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way, but it's not `safe` to rely on, since you cannot detect if a key is currently down in JavaScript.

The example below works only with Shift + Number. It's closest to achieve when both keys are pressed.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
     if (event.shiftKey) {
          if (/\d/.test(event.code)){
               console.log("SHIFTKEY + Number:"+event.code);
         }  
     }
}, true)
```

Maybe you can repeat the same login to your code.